# Are negative numbers considered as null in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, integer, negative-number

This might be a stupid question, but I tried finding an answer and did not find anything.

Are negative numbers considered as 'nothing'(null) in vb.net?

Debug mode:

[image: Check this image in debug mode]

Above is a query to db to find me all values where the district is 'value'. Its a list in razor view and Since I did not want anything to be displayed by default, I set the district ID to -1 and since there is nothing of that value in the database, it should return anything.

However, it still returns me the value where district is NULL. How is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative values are not null. However, you are using `Or` instead of `OrElse` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx)

Or causes both sides of the statement to be called, and it does not short-circuit. Also, you should call the null check before the value check. If you don't short-circuit with the null check, you'll end up calling a comparison of a null value (`m.DistrictId`) against a non-null value (`districtId`).